# bresenham's line algorithm error

Tags: scala, geometry, bresenham

I had the following code of [bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) which represents adapted to *Scala* Java code.

```
def bresenham(x0: Int, y0: Int, x1: Int, y1: Int) = {
    import scala.math.abs

    val dx = abs(x1 - x0)
    val dy = abs(y1 - y0)

    val sx = if (x0 < x1) 1 else -1
    val sy = if (y0 < y1) 1 else -1

    new Iterator[(Int, Int)] {
      var (x, y) = (x0, y0)
      var err = dx - dy

      def next = {
        val omitted = (x, y)
        val e2 = 2 * err
        if (e2 > -dy) {
          err -= dy
          x += sx
        }
        if (e2 < dx) {
          err += dx
          y += sy
        }
        omitted
      }

      def hasNext = (x <= x1 && y <= y1)
    }
  }
```

For almost all lines all goes fine, but when I'm trying to compute vertical lines from top to bottom (i.e. **(0,3) -> (0,0)** ) I'm getting nothing.
I feel stupid about myself, because problem is not so hard and lies in `hasNext` which says *nope* for a case above).
I've dealt with that by swapping points, but that's obviously a bad solution. 
Can anybody help me to generalize algorithm?

Comment: unfortunately, your approach leads to ` ThrowableException: Java heap space` (that's because `hasNext` mostly becomes `true`, when it's actually shouldn't and line goes to infinity).

Comment: incidentally, I've found another bug in this code -- line between the same points (e.g. (0,0) -> (0,0)) gives infinite loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the failure case, you're trying to go from `y0 = 3` to `y1 = 0`. So the step will be negative, `sy = -1`. The condition for continuing in `hasNext` should then depend on `y >= y1` rather than what you wrote (`y <= y1`).

`hasNext` must be generalized to handle either direction. A clever way would be,

```
def hasNext = (sx*x <= sx*x1 && sy*y <= sy*y1)
```

which works because `sx` and `sy` are nonzero, and their sign determines the direction of the steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @jeela answer seems to be prettiest and easy (multiplications are heavy) but I'm getting all points except last one. Your answer is both correct and fine.

Answer (score 2):

A rather literal translation of wikipedia code would be:

```
def hasNext = (!(x==x1 && y==y1))
```